# Paging on View with MVC Paged List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanna implement MVC paging so on the Index Action its working.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
        {   

            CustomersViewModel model = new CustomersViewModel();
            //model.Customers = db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.CustomerID).OrderByDescending(m=>m.CustomerID).Take(10).ToList();
            model.Customers = db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.CustomerID).OrderByDescending(m=>m.CustomerID).Take(10).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,5);
            model.SelectedCustomer = null;

            var list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }

            SelectList selectedList = new SelectList(list);
            ViewBag.DdList = selectedList;

            //model.Countries = db.Countries.ToList();
            model.CountryList = new SelectList(BLDDLCountry.GetCountry(), "CountryId", "CountryName"); 
            model.DisplayMode = "WriteOnly";
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Now on the View

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {page, pagesize = 5 }))
```

Is accepted only if i decorate my View Model with IPagedList

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SingleCRUD.Models.CustomersViewModel>
```

Now as I am using

```
 public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

On My ViewModdel
 The View is not accepting the Customers

```
@{
            foreach (var item in Model.Customers)
             {
            if (Model.SelectedCustomer != null)
            {
                if (item.CustomerID == 
                    Model.SelectedCustomer.CustomerID)
                {
                    @:<tr class="SelectedCustomer">
                }
                else
                {
                    @:<tr>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                @:<tr>
            }
            <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
            <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
            @*<td><input type="submit" 
                 formaction="/home/select/@item.CustomerID" 
                 value="Select" /></td>*@
            <td><input type="submit"
                   formaction="/home/Edit/@item.CustomerID"
                   value="Edit" /></td>
            <td></td>
            @:</tr>
        }
        }
```

And Go to definition has stopped on Customers after changing the name space.
My View Model

```
public class CustomersViewModel 
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Phone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Fax { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public Customer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMode { get; set; }

    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
}
```

So I am facing issue at the view level how do I correctly fix it.

Tried these changes

Model

```
public PagedList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

View

```
@model SingleCRUD.Models.CustomersViewModel
@using PagedList; 
@using PagedList.Mvc;
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Customers, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pagesize = 5 }))
```

Action

```
model.Customers = (PagedList<Customer>)db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.CustomerID).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5);
```

Had to explicitly convert it to Paged List as there was a conversion error not sure whether its correct.

Run Time error on View.

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, PagedList.IPagedList, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

Error

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'PagedList.IPagedList' to 'PagedList.PagedList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Using

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Customers, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pagesize = 5 }))
```

on View tried writing this in the form tag as well as out side the form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit unclear what you claiming. `@model PagedList.IPagedList<CustomersViewModel>` will **not** work since your model is `CustomersViewModel` but it will work if your use `@model CustomersViewModel`.

If you wanting to display a paged list of `Customer`, then your model property needs to be

```
public IPagedList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

and in the view use

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Customers, page => Url.Action("Index", new {page, pagesize = 5 }))
```

Comment: You need to edit your question with new code you have tried, not edit my answer (your edit has been rejected)

Comment: You should not need the explicit to `PagedList` - what error were you getting?

Comment: Try making the property in the model `public IPagedList<Customer> Customers { get; set; }`

Comment: Tried. Error on action is gone but on view it remains the same.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Are you sure your using `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Customers, ...)`? Are the `using` statements are included in the view.

Comment: Have posted the exact code of view. above.Under heading using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104132/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dave).